# How to safeTransfer an ERC20?

Tags: erc-20, tokens, transfer, safe

I have to `safeTransfer` an `ERC20` to a smart contract. How can I do this?

I understand that `SafeERC20` is not an extension of `ERC20`, this is why I don't understand how I am able to interact with safe functions if there is not an actual deploy of it.

Do I have to deploy my own "safe" smart contract and wrap the `ERC20` I want to send in order to be able to use `safeTransfer`?

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/137882/why-does-uniswap-v2-use-safetransfer-to-transfer-tokens/137884#137884 explains what safeTransfer is. It doesn't make the ERC20 standard 'safe', whatever that means, it just ensures that your transfer will work with all allowed implementations of the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To safely transfer an ERC20 token to a smart contract, you can use the SafeERC20 library to wrap the ERC20 token in a "safe" contract. This allows you to use the safe transfer functions provided by the library. You can follow this example where I "safe transfer" the tokens to the contract itself.

```
import {IERC20, SafeERC20} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";

contract SafeTransferToken {
    IERC20 private token;
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

    constructor(address tokenAddress) {
        token = IERC20(tokenAddress);
    }

    function transferTokensToContract(uint256 amount) external {
        // I'm transferring the tokens to this contract
        token.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
    }
}
```